# 301 redirect from "/index.html" to root if index.html not exist

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, directory-index

Can I create 301 redirect from "index.html" to root directory if file "index.html" not exist?

For example: link "`http://example.com/index.html`"  show "404 Error" page.

I need 301 redirect to root directory: "`http://example.com/`"

in .htaccess I add rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work.
Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*?/|)index\.html$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

If Request Filename ends with `index.html` AND if `index.html` does not exists, then redirect it to `http://example.com`

*Try below rewrite rule:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Above rule works for me

Comment: Doesn't work, this rule show 310 redirect on all pages. (I mean firs rule)
2nd rule don't change anything

Comment: Try this one RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$ /test.php?a=$1 [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: RewriteRule is not properly visible in comments, so updated by answer

Comment: The same 404error
Thanks for try, maybe you know where can be this problem?

Comment: can you check Firebug -> Net? Is RewriteRule is giving 404 or it gives 404 after redirecting to http://example.com/$1

Comment: Only 404 without redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this one:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301]
```

I'm sorry, for I forgot something. It's now edited!

---

Try this second one!

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Doesnt work, maybe you know reason for this?

Comment: Have you ever tried to run the code by itself? Now, check the updates' new code if it will going to work.